# How to add a graphic table element in Python without Production Mapping extension?

Tags: arcpy

I'd like to add a table in the Map Layout that includes only items visible at the current extent of the dataset. I know that the Production Mapping Extension lets you insert a Graphic Table Element filtered by the dataset current extent (I suppose). But we haven't this extension.

Has anyone ever tried to do something like this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

There is a script near the bottom of [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000040000000) that will add a table to a map layout by building it as a set of lines and text from a table that you have added to the map document.

> The following script will construct a graphic table based on data values from a table in the map document. The map document was authored with a vertical line named vertLine, a horizontal line named horzLine, and a text element named TableText. Each of the elements were authored with the appropriate symbology properties. The element's anchors were also set to the upper left position and the text element's vertical and horizontal justification were set to top left.